# convert c++ new float allocation to c#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm porting a c++ library to c#. How can I convert this line of c++ code to c# equivalent?

```
mpixels = new float[mwidth * mheight];
```

`mpixel` is a `float*` field that is used many times in the class and the code is **performance critical** So I rather keep the pointers and not use arrays.

I tried allocating unmanaged heap with `Marshal.AllocateHGlobal` but I don't understand how to use the resulting `IntPtr` to apply on the float*.

Comment: looks like it could be an array of floats.

Comment: Yes. But the code is about pixel manipulations and the performance is of utmost importance here. Having pointer arithmetics could perform so much better than jagged arrays.

Comment: c# has unsafe code...

Comment: Yes. The context is unsafe

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent C# code is:

```
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(mwidth*mheight*sizeof (float));
        mpixels = (float*) ptr.ToPointer();
```

Comment: If you need to write C# like this, then why not leave the code in C++?

Comment: Well... The development stack is based on C# and I have experience in C# not in C++ :( And above all I can't just use the C++ library because it has logical bugs and the performance is terrible. So I have to port it to C# and the optimize and partially rewrite the code.